# How can I fix pyaudio ImportError on termux?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyaudio, termux

While importing pyaudio I am running into an error:

```
>>> import pyaudio
Could not import the PyAudio C module '_portaudio'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyaudio.py", line 116, in <module>
    import _portaudio as pa
ImportError: dlopen failed: library "libpulse.so" not found: needed by /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/libportaudio.so in namespace (default)
```

I've installed pyaudio as it is in [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/2962&ved=2ahUKEwj6pZb97bD1AhVCiqQKHUQ5AgYQFnoECAkQAQ&usg=AOvVaw3m6x43lFbwIW800gHWSxrX) tutorial.
I've tried `pkg install libpulse` (hasn't found package)

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You should install "PortAudio" pacakage from [here](http://www.portaudio.com/download.html).

Then restart your pc and try again!

Comment: Or uninstall the old version and install new version by "pip install PyAudio"